# Function to update last sensor value in Django

Tags: python, django, api, sensors

I have created an API for several environmental sensors using models. I am trying to create a function to receive the latest value from the Django database and retrieve it.

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class SensorStation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sensor(models.Model):
    sensor_type_choices = [
        ("TEMP", "Temperature"),
        ("HUMID", "Humidity"),
        ("LIGHT", "Light"),
    ]
    sensor_unit_choices = [
        ("Celsius", "Cel"),
        ("Humidity", "hmd"),
        ("Light", "lgt")
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sensor_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=sensor_type_choices)
    sensor_unit = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=sensor_unit_choices)
    station = models.ForeignKey(SensorStation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.get_sensor_type_display()})"

    def update_latest_value(self, val):
        latest_value = Sensor.objects.filter(value=val).latest("timestamp")
        if latest_value:
            self.value = latest_value.value
            self.timestamp = latest_value.timestamp
            self.save()
        else:
            self.value = 21.21 #for debugging purposes
            self.timestamp = None
            self.save()
...
```

This function doesn't work, as the API returns this json:

Also, this is my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Sensor, SensorStation, SensorValue
from .serializers import SensorSerializer, SensorStationSerializer, SensorValueSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SensorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Sensor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SensorSerializer


class SensorDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Sensor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SensorSerializer


class SensorTypeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SensorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        sensor_type = self.kwargs["sensor_type"]
        return Sensor.objects.filter(sensor_type=sensor_type)


class SensorStationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = SensorStation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SensorStationSerializer


class SensorStationDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = SensorStation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SensorStationSerializer


class StationSensorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SensorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        station_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return Sensor.objects.filter(sensor_station=station_id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        station_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        sensor_station = SensorStation.objects.get(id=station_id)
        serializer.save(sensor_station=sensor_station)
...
```

This is what the API returns

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sensor2",
    "sensor_type": "TEMP",
    "sensor_unit": "Celsius",
    "station": 1,
    "value": null,
    "timestamp": null
}
```

The value of the sensor is null.
How can i return the latest value and display it in the json returned by the API?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Sensor.objects.all()
```

use

```
Sensor.objects.filter(value__gt=0).order_by('-id')
```

it will return Sensor objects that in which values are not null will show the latest value as first

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue. It returns:{
    "detail": "Not found."
}